# No value given for one or more required parameters. C#/Access

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

Using C# on VS13 with a connected Access database and am receiving the error "No value given for one or more required parameters" when executing certain SQL.

Here is my code. Thanks for your time!

```
    // ID accessors for an itemLine object
    public void setID(string Value) { ID = Value; } 
    public string getID() { return ID; }

    ...


    // Code snippet where error originates
    foreach (CartItem itemLine in parBasket)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Instock FROM tblProducts WHERE ProductID = " + itemLine.getID() + "";

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        int stock = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Instock"]);

        stock = stock - itemLine.getQuanity();

        reader.Close(); //Close the reader

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProducts SET InStock =" + stock + " WHERE ProductID = " + itemLine.getID() + "";

        updated = updated + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    cn.Close();
    return updated;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! Please post your code in your post. It's a bit difficult to switch between two or more images in order to find out what's went wrong. Thank you. By the way I think that the issue you have steps form the getID method you use. Having read the error you got, I believe that you try to update a row of a table , but you don't provide the corresponding primary key, ID. Please post also the code of this method.

Answer (score 1):

If `CartItem.getID()` returns an integer, not a string, then you need to remove the single quotes around it in the `SELECT` statement you are building.

Even better - read up on using `SqlParameter` and use this when building queries like this, as it helps avoid this sort of error, and also prevents [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), if any of the parameter data comes directly from user input.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input. I removed all the ' and still no joy. What puzzles me is this is taken from another build of a similar website I made and its not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: please can you edit the original question and add the code? That will allow a few others to dive in and help, and maybe get you some up votes (as well as a better answer)

Comment: @AFro2020 it may work in similar projects because the ID may be an integer in those. Another possibility is that you have a typo in some SQL object name? I see `Instock` has variable casing, although highly unlikely your database may be configured with a case-sensitive schema (this is really a stupid thing to do). If none of this work, please post the resulting SQL strings that actually get executed.

Comment: +1 for using SQL parameters. _Please_ do. Here's a bonus tip: using a library like `Dapper` would make even simpler. Look at it, you'll love it _much_ better than raw ADO.NET code.

Comment: Sadly the caseing wasn't an issue. I will post the SQL that updates the table below.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProducts SET InStock =" + stock + " WHERE ProductID = " + itemLine.getID() + "";

Comment: Is that what your looking for? / Cheers Il look into it for future stuff!

Comment: Also I took out the ' and it made no difference. Does the code bellow  help?

Comment: private string ProductID, ProductName, ProductColour, ProductDimensions, ImageFile;
    private double price;
    private int stock;

Comment: @jods - feel free to move this discussion over to an answer of your own, so that OP can give you credit for it

Answer (score 1):

To fix those errors yourself, you should:

1. Run with the debugger;
2. When the SQL command throws an exception the debugger should break (at least if it's unhandled. If you catch it, the debugger may still break but you have to tweak its config to do so);
3. Use a Watch or something to look at the CommandText of your SqlCommand (i.e. the SQL text that actually gets executed).

This should make pretty obvious what is wrong.

Now using my Crystal ball rather than a debugger, I think your problem is that `getId()` returns a string (per your comment on the question) and you end up with something like: `WHERE ProductID = FortyTwo` in both the first and second SQL queries.

The bad solution to this would be to enclose the string in quotes: `WHERE ProductID = 'FortyTwo'` but you should be careful that your ID doesn't contain a quote itself (which you should escape).

The good solution is to use a SQL parameter. Assuming SQL Server syntax: `WHERE ProductID = @id` and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", item.GetId())`. (Note: you use the same command repeatedly, you should *not* add the parameter repeatedly. Rather, add it once and then change its value at each iteration.)

Comment: I used the debug and It pointed to the error. I am unsure that you mean on your "good solution"

Comment: Glad that you found out the error. The 'good solution' is not to perform string concatenation to build your SQL queries, rather use parameterized queries. Google it, but here's a very quick intro: http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/ .

Comment: Cheers for the link! Part of me thinks it could be a database error? Due to is saying not all parameters have values.